# Como limpar o cache do IE 10 e 11 através de uma função javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Como limpar o *cache* do IE através de uma função javascript?

Eu quero que toda vez que clicar em um determinado botão, rode uma função que limpe o *cache* do IE 10 e 11.

Eu usei:

```
function atualiza() {
    setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(true); }, 3000);
}

<button ng-click="editar()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md atualizar-edicao" data-dismiss="modal" id="" onclick="atualiza()">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Salvar
</button>
```

Mas ele não limpa o *cache*.

Comment: Como está seu botão?

Comment: @bigown eu adicioniei detalhes na pergunta

Comment: Voce nao pode limpar a **cache** do browser com código

Comment: @BrunoCosta sério? não existe nenhuma forma de forçar isso?

Comment: O @BrunoCosta tem razão, se for o desejo não dá, seria uma enorme quebra de segurança. Se quer apenas que a sua página seja recarregada garantidamente vindo do servidor e não pegue do cache, é só melhorar um pouco esse código e já deve ficar certo. Conforma se é isso.

Comment: @bigown isso é uma solução temporaria, não vou deixar essa solução implementada.  São testes que estou aplicando. O que preciso nesse momento é que force a limpeza do cash, porque quando eu dou refresh, ele não tem o comportamento esperado, agora quando dou o crtl+shift+del e limpo o cash, funciona corretamente. Quando dou apenas esse comando, ele fica mantendo o cash, e não atualiza as informações alteradas

Comment: @bigown é que eu só tenho o resultado esperado, quando limpo o cash, mas se tiver alguma forma de forçar essa atualização, tambem serve, estou aceitando sugestões..

Comment: Então conserte o erro que está impedindo o resultado esperado, não faça gambiarra, que por sorte nem pode.

Comment: @bigown se eu soubesse como resolver teria resolvido com certeza. Vc disse que "apenas que a sua página seja recarregada garantidamente vindo do servidor e não pegue do cache" como faço isso? pode demonstrar?

Comment: Se o problema ta sendo o cache, então desativa ele.